# Copy r output to the report when writing the report

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

How to include (copy) r output directly to the report in kintr (rmarkdown)?

I am writing a report using knitr (rmarkdown) in some paragraph I need to mention the p-value. So, if include the r output directly into the paragraph I don't need to change the value again when the dataset change. Could you please suggest me the way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use in-line calls to report values from previous analyses. For instance:

````
```{r}
y <- 5
```

The value of y that we set was `r y`.
````

This should print:

> The value of y that we set was 5.

So for a linear model you'd just use something like

````
```{r}
y <- runif(100)
x <- rnorm(100)
lmyx <- lm(y~x)
sum.lmyx <- summary(lmyx)
```

The adjusted R-squared of the best fit linear model was `r sum.lmyx$adj.r.squared`
````